# Probabilties of the Universe

Tags: science-based, physics, astronomy, time

Is it plausible that the only way to be at both ends of the Universe at the same time is to have a Mass/Space/energy equivalent of the Universe? In essence is it possible the universe is the only thing that can be at both edges of itself at the same time?

Comment: You make the assumption that the universe is finite? If it's infinite, then there are no edges. Anyway, welcome to World building SE but your question might be more appropriate on the Physic stack exchange.

Comment: There is a finite amount of perceivable stuff in the universe. Mass/Energy/Space. This is why mathematics works.  E=mC<sup>2</sup> means that energy and mass are interchangeable. There is something beyond matter and energy that we simply do not understand yet that effects gravity, discovered in black holes.  Einstein predicted black holes and understood that his equation was wrong because it was missing an unknown variable that was unaccounted for. This is what I'm talking about when I say the "edge". Where the perceivable detectable universe ends. But thanks for the welcome :]

Comment: Chris, Einstein added in the cosmological constant because he wanted a static universe, not be GR was wrong. Second black holes *are* matter and energy. And space *is* thought to be infinite.

Comment: I thought it was an open question as to whether the universe is infinite in space, or even if it's infinite in some directions and finite in others.

Answer (score 0):

Cosmology currently has a number of competing theories regarding the size and shape of the universe. In no models does the universe have an "edge".  In finite models it is described as finite but without boundaries.

What does it mean no have no boundary?  It roughly means that no path through space can come to an end due to the curvature and geometry of space.  Temporal issues and universal limitations on velocity and energy lead to all sorts of problems with the idea of being in two places at once.

The only thing in our universe having the same mass/space/energy of the universe is the universe itself.

Comment: Of course it does not have an edge but there is a place at which there is no mass or space in our current model of the big bang theory. Even if it were infinite it could only be infinite in recurrence. I was just speaking to the metaphorical "edge". The farthest reaches we can yet understand.

Comment: @Chris It is not clear what you mean when you say there is a place at which there is no mass or space.  Our current theory says that "nothing" is impossible.  There can exist no part of our universe that is "nothing".

Comment: Exactly. There is of course no such thing as nothing. But there is something beyond space, mass and energy outside of the confines of our definition of the universe. Nothing with mass can be accelerated to the speed of light. Only photons can travel at the speed of light. Yet in the depths of a black hole even light cannot escape and the mass of an object becomes infinite. Something unknown must be effecting the photons. Its theorized that this "anti-substance" is what is outside the perceivable universe and flows between space and matter without any measurable effect on it. Knowing th